# Unable to start docker on win 10 VM

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

We are unable to launch docker on win 10 VM, following are the error details:

Unable to write to the database. Exit code: 1
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings)
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0(Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters)

Any inputs to resolve the issue would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure. You are trying o host docker containers, on Windows 10 operating system that is running on a VM? if so, then have you made sure that your hardware supports nested virtualization? On most laptops that is a bios option that enables the feature.